# Sorting items with groupOrder visjs timeline

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-timeline

The visjs timeline groupOrder example appears to be able to sort items, but I don't see the code that actually accomplishes this – I only see the code that actually sorts the groups (if it is possible to sort the items with groupOrder that seems preferable to 'item ordering' because the latter has a performance limitation of 300ish items). What is responsible for ordering 'item 2', 'item 3' and 'item 4' in this example?  http://jsfiddle.net/5p0ggwkx/1369/

```
<div id="visualization"></div>

  var groups = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 0, content: 'First', value: 1},
    {id: 1, content: 'Third', value: 3},
    {id: 2, content: 'Second', value: 2}
  ]);

  // create a dataset with items
  // note that months are zero-based in the JavaScript Date object, so month 3 is April
  var items = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, group: 0, content: 'item 1', start: new Date(2014, 3, 19), end: new Date(2014, 3, 20)},

    {id: 0, group: 0, content: 'item 0', start: new Date(2014, 3, 17), end: new Date(2014, 3, 21)},
{id: 2, group: 1, content: 'item 2', start: new Date(2014, 3, 16), end: new Date(2014, 3, 24)},
 {id: 3, group: 1, content: 'item 3', start: new Date(2014, 3, 16), end: new Date(2014, 3, 24)},
{id: 4, group: 1, content: 'item 4', start: new Date(2014, 3, 16), end: new Date(2014, 3, 26)},

{id: 5, group: 2, content: 'item 5', start: new Date(2014, 3, 24), end: new Date(2014, 3, 27)}
  ]);

  // create visualization
  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var options = {
    // option groupOrder can be a property name or a sort function
    // the sort function must compare two groups and return a value
    //     > 0 when a > b
    //     < 0 when a < b
    //       0 when a == b
    groupOrder: function (a, b) {
      return a.value - b.value;
    },
    editable: true
  };

  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container);
  timeline.setOptions(options);
  timeline.setGroups(groups);
  timeline.setItems(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

To order items inside a group you can use `order` option as per the [docs](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options). You can find a better explanation and a working demo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555787/visjs-timeline-sorting-items-in-timeline/54890183#54890183).

Comment: The working demo mentioned is not working. Can you provide an actual working demo please?

Comment: Checkout this demo http://jsfiddle.net/rexzing/4m0683sd/1/ . @Ventolinmono